# For which p does $v_p$ have an anti-derivative?

Tags: integration, vector-fields, line-integrals

On $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and for real $p$ let $v_p$ be the vector field:
$$
v_p(x,y):=\left(\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^p}, \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^p}\right)$$
For which $p>0$ is there an open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ such, that $v_p$ has an anti-derivative on U? For these p, give U and an anti-derivative of $v_p$.

This is an old exam question, which I think I've got all wrong. My Solution attempt: Check whether the path integral for the path $\gamma: [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$defined as $$\gamma(t) = \big(\sin(t), -\cos(t)\big)^t$$ vanishes. It doesn't, for any p, as it is always equal to $2\pi$. But I feel I have misunderstood the idea of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $v_p=\nabla\phi$ then $\partial_y(v_p)_1=\partial_x(v_p)_2$, i.e. $$\frac{-x^2+(2p-1)y^2}{x(x^2+y^2)^{p+1}}=-\partial_y y(x^2+y^2)^{-p}=\partial_x x(x^2+y^2)^{-p}=\frac{(1-2p)x^2+y^2}{x(x^2+y^2)^{p+1}},$$which simplifies to $p=1$. Indeed, in that case we may take $$\phi=\arctan\frac{y}{x}.$$Your path integral approach failed because of the jump discontinuity in $\phi$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly: if and only if $p=1$ $v_p$ has an anti-derivative over _any_ open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$?

Comment: @RubenKruepper The derivative-matching argument precludes derivatives on open sets when $p\ne1$. When $p=1$, I think $\phi$ should be a valid choice of antiderivative on any open $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I read up on that argument. One problem: the derivative-matching argument gives a necessary condition, however, when U is not a star domain, it is not sufficient. So we have as only candidate $p = 1$, but we must still restrict U, as otherwise the path argument via $\gamma$ still shows there is no anti-derivative.

Comment: @RubenKruepper Fortunately, the original problem only requires there to be some open $U$ on which $v_p=\nabla\phi$.  You can choose e.g. $(x-1)^2+y^2<\frac14$ so no $x=0$ point is in $U$..

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For anyone who might stumble across this: If you graph the vector field it is a "swirl" around the origin. If we exclude the x-axis from U, then we can't just go "around and around" the swirl and the line integral for closed paths will again vanish.